# Separating characters by a delimiter into vectors assuming fixed width

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, tidyr

I have the following character data,

```
v1 <- c("1321-56, 21-, 15-, 1701-13,", "1305-25, 2101-03, 1501-02, 1711-55,", "1309-18, 21-, 1501-04, 1701-15,")
data <- data.frame(v1)
> data
                                   v1
1         1321-56, 21-, 15-, 1701-13,
2 1305-25, 2101-03, 1501-02, 1711-55,
3     1309-18, 21-, 1501-04, 1701-15,
```

The separated by comma, each part of the character rows are to be divided into 3 parts. The character numbers should be 2, 5 and 6 respectively. For example,

- `1321-56` should be distributed into three vectors like `13` (2 characters), `00021` (5 characters) and `000056` (6 characters).
- `15-` should be distributed into three vectors like `15, 00000` and `000000`. etc.

The final output should be like this,

```
> data1
  v1a   v1b    v1c v2a   v2b    v2c v3a   v3b    v3c v4a   v4b    v4c
1  13 00021 000056  21 00001 000000  15 00000 000000  17 00001 000013
2  13 00005 000025  21 00001 000003  15 00000 000000  17 00011 000055
3  13 00009 000018  21 00000 000000  15 00000 000000  17 00001 000015
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are there always 4 groups? (`v1` to `v4`)

Comment: Try perhaps adding the 0s with `stri_sub` from `stringi` ?

Comment: Good point. The answer is no. It could be two non-sequential digits, ranging from 01 to 99. @JuliusVainora

Comment: But it is a common number to all the rows, right?

Comment: Yes, for example the marker `13`, `21` or `15` would be in the same place in the next row. @JuliusVainora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach in two steps with `str_match` and `sprintf`. First we split everything:

```
n <- 4 # or str_count(v1, ",")[1] of it's common to all the rows
(M <- str_match(v1, paste0(rep("(\\d{2})(\\d*)-(\\d*)[, ]*", n), collapse = ""))[, -1])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
# [1,] "13" "21" "56" "21" ""   ""   "15" ""   ""   "17"  "01"  "13" 
# [2,] "13" "05" "25" "21" "01" "03" "15" "01" "02" "17"  "11"  "55" 
# [3,] "13" "09" "18" "21" ""   ""   "15" "01" "04" "17"  "01"  "15"
```

giving `3 * n` columns, and then format the matrix with `sprintf`:

```
matrix(sprintf(c("%02s", "%05s", "%06s"), t(M)), nrow = nrow(M), byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2]    [,3]     [,4] [,5]    [,6]     [,7] [,8]    [,9]     [,10] [,11]   [,12]   
# [1,] "13" "00021" "000056" "21" "00000" "000000" "15" "00000" "000000" "17"  "00001" "000013"
# [2,] "13" "00005" "000025" "21" "00001" "000003" "15" "00001" "000002" "17"  "00011" "000055"
# [3,] "13" "00009" "000018" "21" "00000" "000000" "15" "00001" "000004" "17"  "00001" "000015"
```

Comment: Easy, short and smart. Thank you. I am practicing your idea in an easier data. I am having an error, which I have added in the original problem. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @ome, I didn't verify whether the output is what you may want, but the problem is with using `easy`; you need to pass a vector instead, e.g., `easy[, 1]`.

Comment: @ome, no problem. I also removed your update as it's not a part of the initial question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all inputs substrings are of the form `9999-99,` or `99-,` we use one `gsub` to transform the first form to three space separated fields and another `gsub` to transform the second form to three space-separated fields. Finally `read.table` produces a data frame from that.  The `col.names=` argument can be omitted if the column names don't matter. No packages are used.

```
s <- gsub("(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d),", "\\1 000\\2 0000\\3", data$v1)
s2 <- gsub("(\\d\\d)-,", "\\1 00000 000000", s)
read.table(text = s2, colClasses = "character", 
  col.names = paste0("v", rep(1:4, each = 3), letters[1:3]))
```

giving:

```
  v1a   v1b    v1c v2a   v2b    v2c v3a   v3b    v3c v4a   v4b    v4c
1  13 00021 000056  21 00000 000000  15 00000 000000  17 00001 000013
2  13 00005 000025  21 00001 000003  15 00001 000002  17 00011 000055
3  13 00009 000018  21 00000 000000  15 00001 000004  17 00001 000015
```

### `easy` example

Regarding the `easy` example note that the second `<-` in the line defining `easy` in the question should be `=`.   Making that fix and assuming that each substring is to be split into two columns using the first two digits for the first column and the rest for the next column then:

```
s <- gsub("(\\d\\d)(\\d*),", "\\1,\\2,", easy$v1)
read.table(text = s, colClasses = "character", sep = ",")[-15]
```

giving;

```
  V1   V2  V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14
1 01 0718  02    03    04 16 05  11  06      07    
2 01 0819  02 11 03 22 04  2 05  21  06   2  07  21
3 01 0819  02  1 03  2 04  6 05   1  06  11  07  01
```